# 'proceed >>' link is not accessible to keyboard users on How to Ask page

Tags: bug, accessibility

The 'proceed >>' link on the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) page can't be tabbed to.

Seems like you definitely should be able to?

(Not sure how keyboard-only users get past this screen.)

Comment: _"(Not sure how keyboard-only users get past this screen.)"_ - either you or I are going to be surprised about the number of keyboard-only users.

Comment: They can tab to *Ask Question*, though, and that takes you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, as does `Proceed >>`. Agreed that it's far from obvious.

Comment: You also cannot select the check box 'I will keep that in mind' with the keyboard.

Comment: @Yvette Yes you can. The space bar activates a checkbox or radio.

Comment: @CodeCaster note the accessibility tag on the question. proper keyboard navigation is a fundamental aspect of accessibility

Comment: @ken I do know about the importance of accessibility, it was just a joke.

Comment: Could you specify which link you are referring to? I can't find a link labeled `proceed >>` and I can tab to the only other link with `>>` which is "discuss on meta".

Comment: @Arc676 At the bottom right of the screen. The text is small and easy to miss.

Comment: @Renzeee I actually used the Find function on my browser and "proceed" wasn't found. Does it only appear if you get there from a certain place?

Comment: @Arc676 Unicode is used, and the button is actually labelled `proceed »` rather than `proceed >>`.

Comment: @bcsb1001 I just searched `proceed`. I also tried copying the `»` from `discuss on meta »` but that wasn't found either.

Comment: @Arc676 Hmm, that's curious. What it looks like to me is [this](http://i.imgur.com/vDULY46.png).

Comment: @bcsb1001 I just see white. Interestingly, the link itself can still be found in the HTML.

Comment: I like how the form that the _proceed »_ is using javascript to submit is called `theForm`.